# How to store large data in next js session or use session file storage?

Tags: node.js, express, session, next.js

I want to store user data in session. How can I store large data in session like we can use in express session file store.

Answer (score 0):

There's this library: https://github.com/hoangvvo/next-session

But pay attention to this line:

> Project status: While there will be bug fixes, it is unlikely that next-session will receive features PR in the future. Consider using alternatives like express-session+next-connect or next-iron-session instead.

Comment: there is no great ref to use this pkg with stores other than memory